# need to alter column type to NOT NULL AUTO_INCREAMENT using ALTER COLUMN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to change the column "ID" which is currently type INTEGER but have NULL values into type INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT. But I am getting error. My SQL syntax is as follows.

```
ALTER TABLE users
ALTER COLUMN ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The above code is giving me syntax error.

Then I tried,

```
ALTER TABLE users
ALTER COLUMN ID INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

This is also giving me syntax error like

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTEGER NOT NULL' at line 2

Comment: Please read Reference manual. There are ALTER COLUMN, CHANGE COLUMN and MODIFY COLUMN, each performs its own actions. And you don't need to specify NOT NULL - AUTO_INCREMENT must be primary key, all columns mentioned in its expresion are set to NOT NULL automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MODIFY COLUMN`:

```
ALTER TABLE users
MODIFY COLUMN ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

There's also an ALTER COLUMN type of command, but it's only for specifying the DEFAULT for a column. Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html for examples.

Comment: thank you, it works for me, and I made the column a primary key too.